# Can't use sweet alert in page_load in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am using SweetAlert.js with asp.net webform project. Imported js and css file in to masterpage and showing message on button click example is working fine.

I would like to show message on page_load when data is not loaded. I have tried but get an error:

```
reference error. "swal is not defined"
```

How can we fix this, how can we use sweetalert on page_load? Need your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When swal is not working on page_load:

```
swal("something");
```

Try this and it is nice solution for it. It waits until document is ready and error  disappears.

```
$(document).ready(function(){swal("something");}); // It works.
```

I hope it helps who has faced same issue.